# Android PageKeyedDataSource (paging library) callback error handling (there is TODO exception in src)

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging, android-paging-library

I want to pass an error exception to my paging adapter via callback.onError(or callback.onRetryableError) in *loadInitial* or *loadafter* but always receive crashes. 
After some debugging I find this in library sources:
[image]

It's actually what I'm receiving in my crash trace. Just "todo".
Dependency version:

> 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:2.1.1'

Does it ok to have such kind of exception message on production at all or I did something wrong? 
Anyway...
Question: any other 'builtin' ways to pass loading error to adapter?

Comment: Well, in 2.1.2 instead of fixing it they just remove onError & onRetryableError at all.

Comment: it is terrible when the page load failed, it did not give any method.